# Toshiba 2800-200 lubuntu installation failure

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, usb-drive

So I have an old toshiba running win ME, and I want to use it again. I thought I could just install lubuntu with a pen drive. The problem is when I choose the installation mode, it freezes until i turn off the laptop. Or it returns a message saying kernel panic. I realise that I might need to install some drivers but i don't know how.

Comment: win ME? How old is that thing? You are a boss even for just trying to get that working! Do you have the minimal system requirements? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help? You can try the minimal installer or the other options explained here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems

Comment: Could you say what exactly you tried and what worked? so I can include it in my answer. If this answer helped you, can you mark it as accepted?